# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - ELB processes are not healthy on all instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new in Flask and trying to deploy my "HelloWorld" app into AWS Elastic Beanstalk. So, I have an health error like shown below:
[image]

I tried some recommendations mentioned in below post but they do not work for me:
[AWS:ELB health is failing or not available for all instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212033/awselb-health-is-failing-or-not-available-for-all-instances)

Could you please help?

Comment: There are lots of things to check but is your app returning 200 at the endpoint that your healthcheck is looking?

Comment: I just checked the logs and the response code is 499 and see that message once I go to the link: 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557